# How can I add a horizontal scroll bar at bottom of this table?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

The table contains large amount of columns such that when the browser is restored down the last columns are invisible to the user. I want to add a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the table so the user can drag it and see the last columns.

```
<div class="col-md-12 well">
  <div id="double-scroll">
    <table id="dataGrid" class="dataGrid display dataTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="display:none;">&nbsp;</th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.Event_Name') }} </th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.organization_name') }}</th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.Event_Start_Date') }} </th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.Event_End_Date') }} </th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.Event_Start_Time') }} </th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.Event_End_Time') }} </th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.Event_Location') }} </th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.Event_Venue') }} </th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.Event_Url') }} </th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.Created_Date') }} </th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th style="display:none;">&nbsp;</th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.Event_Name') }} </th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.organization_name') }}</th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.Event_Start_Date') }} </th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.Event_End_Date') }} </th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.Event_Start_Time') }} </th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.Event_End_Time') }} </th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.Event_Location') }} </th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.Event_Venue') }} </th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.Event_Url') }} </th>
          <th>{{ Lang::get('messages.Created_Date') }} </th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>

      <tbody id="mailTableBody">
        @foreach ($liveEvents as $value)
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
          <td style="display:none;" class="sorting_1">{{ $value->id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $value->eventName }}</td>
          <td>{{ $value->organizationName }}</td>
          <td>{{ $value->startDate }}</td>
          <td>{{ $value->endDate }}</td>
          <td>{{ $value->startTime }}</td>
          <td>{{ $value->endTime }}</td>
          <td>{{ $value->location }}</td>
          <td>{{ $value->Venue }}</td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-danger" style ="height: 32px;" href="{{ $value->publicURL }}" >{{Lang::get('messages.register')}}</a></td>
          <td>{{ $value->created_at }}</td>

          <td><button onclick="watchnow(this)" class="btn btn-success" style ="width: 150px; float: right" >{{Lang::get('messages.watchnow')}}</button></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you add css code below:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #double-scroll {
        overflow:scroll
    }
</style>
```

please code above inside `<head>`

---

Note: overflow-x and overflow-y support on latest version of browser if you want to support old ie you need to use overflow:scroll

Comment: can you be more specific about the place where I need to add this part

Answer (score 0):

Add this style:

```css
#datagrid{
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the best answer..

```
<style type="text/css">
    #double-scroll { overflow: auto; overflow-y: hidden; }
    #double-scroll p { margin: 0; padding: 1em; white-space: nowrap; }
</style>
```